# Make the scroll transition between a scroll view and a table view smooth in XCode

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm building this app and have run into the following issue. (pictures included below)

I have 2 view controllers: A and B. View controller B is embedded into View controller A through addChildViewController.

View controller B is a tableview with a segment controller.
View controller B is inside a scroll view owned by view controller A.

What I want:
I want all the subviews (except the scroll view) to remain static at all times.
Since the tableview will have many items, I want the user to be able to scroll it to expand it like shown in the picture. Once it reaches the top, it should not scroll any further. Instead the actual tableview should start scrolling. 
I would like this to be super smooth. As the user swipes his finger up, the entire view controller B should start going up; once it reaches the top, the scroll should immediately transfer to the table view. (hope that made sense)

What I have tried so far:
Playing around with activating and deactivating the shouldEnableScroll properties of both the tableview in view controller B and the scroll View in view controller A

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated
Thanks in advance

http://s1318.photobucket.com/user/Jose_Bigio/media/photo-2_zpsfe1c7b1a.jpg.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This method. This is done in swift

Use PanGesture to drag 'viewcontroller B' Up and down. Then you dont require any scrollview to be added or directly use UIView's

```
    dragRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleDrag:")
    dragRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    dragRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    viewControllerB.addGestureRecognizer(dragRecognizer)
```

Then use handle drag method. declare a variable viewHeight as CGFloat, and assign a value to it as viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - viewControllerB.frame.origin.y

Now using this viewHeight frame, increase your tableview height. Once and handle drag method in such a way that it will not be dragged beyond 200 (or some origin.y of viewController B) and not below 20. See the method below. This is not 100% solution but u can edit as per your requirements.

```
    func handleDrag(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {


    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        touchLocation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view) //returns CGPoint.
        println("Touch location: \(touchLocation)")
        if (touchLocation.y == 0) && (touchLocation.x != 0) {
            isVertical = false
        }else {
            isVertical = true
        }

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {

        translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view)
        println("translation: \(translation)")
        newLocation = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y + translation.y);
        println("New location: \(newLocation)")  // this is for vertical increase or decrease
        var checkPos = CGPoint()
        checkPos = CGPointMake(0, recognizer.view.frame.origin.y + newLocation.y)
        println("Check Position: \(checkPos)")   // 
        var diff = CGFloat()
        if isVertical == true {

            if (checkPos.y > 20 && checkPos.y < 200) {

                newY = checkPos.y   // newY is CGFloat and is used to define new origin of viewcontrollerB

            }else{
                if (checkPos.y < 85) {

                    newY = 85;


                }else if (checkPos.y >= 200){
                    newY = 200


                }
            }

            viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - newY;
            println("viewHeight: \(viewHeight)")
            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view)
            println("\(recognizer)")
            viewControllerB.frame = CGRectMake(0, newY, 320, viewHeight)
            table.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewControllerB.frame.origin.y + 40, 320, viewControllerB.frame.size.height - 40)

        }else if isVertical == false {

            println("Horizontal Swipe: \(isVertical)")

        }


    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended){
        var velocity = CGPoint()
        velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(recognizer.view)
        println("Velocity : \(velocity)")



        }



    }

}
```

May be this will help you to increase your development further. Hope this will help you.  Ignore this if already solved.